# Does unattended-upgrades work in a guest account?

Tags: upgrade, unattended-upgrades

I have a scenario where the only user account to be used is the guest account. There's an admin account to be used only for maintenance.

I have installed `unattended-upgrades`; will it work as intended? Will it perform the upgrades on background while the guests are logged, or only if I periodically login as admin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unattended upgrades will work with guests (or any user), as they do not require a user to be logged in to run.

For more information there is a good Ubuntu community help page: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticSecurityUpdates#Using_the_.22unattended-upgrades.22_package

It explains about how unattended-upgrades is invoked from cron and the various configuration options that can be set.